# jQuery: Manipulating CSS

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to change the style of a button (which is really just a `div`).  I can do it in CSS with `.classname:active`, but the button only changes style while it is being clicked; it doesn't maintain the style changes after the click is released.  So, I decided to use jQuery to manipulate the CSS.  It is worth noting that I am also using Bootstrap and Angular in my application.

**HTML**

```
<div class="subcontainer">
    <div class="center" data-container="body" popover-template="'popover-template.html'"> 
        {{instance}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".subcontainer").click(function() {
        $(this).css("border", "1px inset gray");
    });
});
```

I have also tried using `$(".subcontainer").on("click", function () { ... });`, but to no avail.  I looked at jQuery UI but I don't think it has a quick-fix solution to what I'm trying to achieve, so I'd like to stick with plain jQuery.

EDIT:

The code above works on all elements that aren't nested inside an `ng-repeat`.  I'm trying to solve why it isn't working for those elements inside of an `ng-repeat`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972784/injecting-jquery-into-angularjs-directive if you are trying to use inject jQuery into an AngularJS directive.

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but the standard practice is to apply a css class using jquery, rather than applying specific css properties. so in your css file you could add a class called "clicked", where that class includes a 1px inset gray border, and then in your jquery use addClass or toggleClass to apply the "clicked" class to your element. this keeps your styling separate from your behavior logic.

Comment: i don't see what the problem is. when i replicate your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pdbbyccs/), and click on the div, a border gets applied.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Yeah I see that it works in your fiddle.  I'm not sure why it's not working in my app.  I do have two jQuery files that I wrote.  Perhaps I should combine them?  Also, how would you get that added style to disappear on a second click?

Comment: the easiest thing to do is use `toggleClass` like i was saying above. example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls8q00wn/

Comment: as for your problem, it's probably an interaction with all the libraries and frameworks you're using. use your browser's inspector tools to determine where the conflict is coming from.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the good information!

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow It works for other elements in my application, but doesn't work with anything nested inside an `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change properties of a CSS class with AngularJS and CSS, no jQuery needed.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989985/change-css-classs-property-on-click) for details.  Note that you don't even need a controller like the OP has.

```
<div ng-class="{'gray-inset-border': style}">
    <div ng-click="style=!style">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the this pointer.  Try this intead:

```
$(".subcontainer").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).css("border", "1px inset gray");
});
```

This will pass the general event information into e, then you can get the target of the event using e.target.

EDIT:  In Woodrow's comment above, you could do the same but use '.addClass('isactive')' instead of the direct css manipulation.  The main benefit here is that it is easier to remove later using '.removeClass('isactive')'

Comment: using `$(this)` in the way the OP uses it is a well-known and often-used paradigm in jQuery. there's nothing wrong with the way that part of the code was originally written.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Jquery with angular, the source code in your index page have to be Jquery first then angular like below:

```
<script src ="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src ="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

You need to use the $(".subcontainer") to angular.element('.subcontainer').
 if not,you may have warning or error,when run "grunt serve".

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this;

html

```
<div class="subcontainer">
    <div class="center" data-container="body" popover-template="'popover-template.html'"> 
        BUTTON
    </div>
</div>
```

js using jquery

```
$( ".subcontainer" ).click(function() {

    $(this).addClass("green");

});
```

css

```
.subcontainer
{
    background-color:red;
    width:120px;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
.green
{
   background-color:green; 
}
.center
{
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here's the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Laky/u51vudkt/)

In the example I just change the button colour, but you can configure the dynamically setting class to have any style values as you like.